# Implementing verbose in C

Tags: c, verbose

I'm implementing a verbose mode. Here's what I attempt to do : defining a global variable VERBOSE (in verbose.h) in such way that files requiring verbose only need to include that file. For example :

## verbose.h:

```
void setVerbose(int test);
```

## verbose.c:

```
#include "verbose.h"

// define VERBOSE if called
void setVerbose(int test) {
    if (test) {
        #ifndef VERBOSE
        #define VERBOSE
        #endif
    }
}
```

## point.h:

```
typedef struct Point Point;
struct Point {
    int x, y;
};

void printPoint(Point *point);
```

## point.c:

```
#include "point.h"
#include "verbose.h"

void printPoint(Point *point) {
    #ifdef VERBOSE
        printf("My abscissa is %d\n", point->x);
        printf("My ordinate is %d\n", point->y);
    #endif

    printf("[x,y] = [%d, %d]\n", point->x, point->y);
}
```

And the main :

## main.c:

```
#include "verbose.h"
#include "point.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc >= 2 && !strcmp(argv[1], "-v"))
        setVerbose(1);

    Point *p = init_point(5,7);
    printPoint(p);

    return 0;
}
```

The executable has been produced with :

```
$ gcc -o test main.c point.c verbose.c
```

The outputs wanted are :

```
$ ./test
    [x,y] = [5, 7]

$ ./test -v
    My abscissa is 5
    My ordinate is 7
    [x,y] = [5, 7]
```

Problem is, it seems that VERBOSE is not defined in point.c when calling printPoint().

Comment: Please re-read the concept of a pre-processor.

Comment: `#define` is a **preprocessor** directive. Putting a #define inside an if statement is pointless. That `#define` is translated before the program is compiled.

Comment: The others have mentioned the problem, therefore I will just suggest you to use a **logging class** instead of your current approach. It's much more flexible. For example, I wrote one for Arduino some time ago https://abrushforeachkeyboard.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/arduino-adding-a-logger-class-with-a-c-style-print-of-messages/

Comment: @PatrickTrentin That's C++, so probably not applicable in this case. For the author, if you want to see a bare minimum logging solution, you can look at the C logger I wrote. I'm pretty sure it works,:-) and has an example of what you're trying to do  https://github.com/ccs19/CCS_CLogger

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider of course, it also contains references to libraries he can't run at all. It was just to hint a better idea to handle versatile logging. Your solution rocks too. :)

Comment: Why are you doing things this weird way rather than normal stuff like `extern int verbose;` .. `int verbose = 0; void setVerbose () { verbose=1; }` and so on?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I've tried this way, but when including verbose.h (containing    extern int verbose; .. int verbose = 0), I've got  an error "multiple definition of `verbose'.

@ChristopherSchneider I'm having a look. Thanks.

Comment: @Eamnea So you decided that rather than trying to fix the error or ask how to fix the error, you would try something made up that bears no correspondence to anything legal in C?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Well, basically, yes.

Comment: @Eamnea That's because you're defining the variable itself in the header file. You need to define it in a separate file (i.e. `verbose.c`) and provide the declaration in the header file (`extern int verbose`).

Answer (score 7):

Preprocessor commands are decided at compile time, not run time, so your system won't work.  What I would recommend instead is using a global `bool Verbose` and providing a `verbose()` function to do the printing (or not).

**verbose.h**

```
#include <stdbool.h>

int verbose(const char * restrict, ...);
void setVerbose(bool);
```

**verbose.c**

```
#include "verbose.h"
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool Verbose = false;

void setVerbose(bool setting) {
    Verbose = setting;
}

int verbose(const char * restrict format, ...) {
    if( !Verbose )
        return 0;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int ret = vprintf(format, args);
    va_end(args);

    return ret;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "verbose.h"
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    verbose("Verbose is off\n");

    setVerbose(true);

    verbose("Verbose is on\n");

    int foo = 42;

    verbose("Number: %d\n", foo);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Preprocessor commands are decided at compile time* - This is not correct. The pre-processor kicks in before the compiler

Comment: @EdHeal You are technically correct! ...and it doesn't change the answer one bit. The important thing is it doesn't happen at runtime. I can't figure out how to explain pre-processor vs compile vs run time without needlessly complicating the answer, maybe you can in your own answer or an edit?

Comment: I will have a think of explaining this in easy terms for the poster